# Does ayurveda has medicine for cancer?

Tags: scripture, translation-request, ayurveda

I've heard about ayurvedic treatments for complete cure of cancer but can't validate it. So, I want to know does ayurveda or siddha has this medicine ?

Where can I find/get original Ayurveda and complete medicinal notes?

Comment: @sv do you have  links for ayurveda files

Comment: @sv do you know any of our users knowing ayurveda friend

Comment: @sakti Have you seen this [article](https://thetruthaboutcancer.com/ayurvedic-treatment-for-cancer/)? BTW yes you're right there are many fake ads for cancer treatments. As far as I've read and understood, I believe Ayurveda can treat all kind of infections and diseases but no one knows all the secrets of Ayurveda. Nature has a lot of secrets hidden in it.

Comment: @sakthi See this meta post: [How much of Ayurveda is accepted here?](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7) -- I don't think your question is on-topic for this site. Try asking same in http://biology.stackexchange.com/